# Refer List entrys to a ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, list, combobox, reference

Situation: I have 3 TextBoxes, a button and a ComboBox. When I enter something in every TextBox and trigger the button, I want that the strings I've written in the TextBoxes can be choosen in the ComboBox as a ComboBoxItem. I've got the idea of putting the strings from the TextBoxes into a list and refer the ComboBoxItem to the correct list-entrys. Or is there a more efficient way to set and get these strings?
Would be nice if some could help me writing the code for it.

```
    private void bAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);


        int txBetrag;
        txBetrag = int.Parse(betrag1.Text);
        int txMonate;
        txMonate = int.Parse(monate1.Text);
        int txZins;
        txZins = int.Parse(zins1.Text);


        List<int> abList = new List<int>();

        comboBox.Items.Add("1");
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to add txBetrag, txMonate and txZins to your comboBox?

Comment: @sr28 I'm trying to save these 3 tx's in a list. And the combobox creates a new item which refers to these 3tx's values.

Comment: you want add three textboxes text to combobox as items.Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to add txBetrag, txMonate and txZins to your combobox then you don't need a list. At the moment you're creating a list, adding nothing to it and then simply adding 1 entry to your comboBox (not even from your list).

To add your items just do:

```
comboBox.Items.Add(int.Parse(betrag1.Text));
comboBox.Items.Add(int.Parse(monate1.Text));
comboBox.Items.Add(int.Parse(zins1.Text));
```

If you really need the list as well (perhaps because it is used elsewhere as well) then you can do the following:

```
abList.Add(int.Parse(betrag1.Text));
abList.Add(int.Parse(monate1.Text));
abList.Add(int.Parse(zins1.Text));
```

Then use the list to populate the comboBox:

```
foreach(var item in abList)
{
    comboBox.Items.Add(item);
}
```

***UPDATE***

Based off your comment it seems like you want **ONE** entry in the comboBox that is effectively the 3 textbox values concatenated together. So you could do something like this:

```
comboBox.Items.Add(betrag1.Text + monate1.Text + zins1.Text);
```

***UPDATE 2***

Following you're last comment regarding the fact that you want 1 comboBox item that refers to the 3 values, but doesn't display them, yes you can do this.

Assuming you won't have duplicate entries in the comboBox you could use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) to map your values to an entry rather than use a list. I'm assuming here that you will have more than 1 entry in your comboBox eventually, otherwise it's a bit pointless having a combobox.

```
var valueComboMapping = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();

valueComboMapping.Add("Entry 1", new int[] {int.Parse(betrag1.Text), int.Parse(monate1.Text), int.Parse(zins1.Text)};
```

This will enable you to add mappings at a later date. You can then use the Dictionary to create the listings in the comboBox like this:

```
foreach(var entry in valueComboMapping.Keys)
{
    comboBox.Items.Add(entry);
}
```

To trigger an event off selecting an item in the comboBox using the [SelectedIndexChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

***Retrieving the Values***

To retrieve your mapped values in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event you can do something like:

```
private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;
    string entryName = (string) comboBox.SelectedItem;

    //retrieve the values from the dictionary using the value of 'entryName'.
    List values = new List<int>();
    if (valueComboMapping.TryGetValue(entryName, out values)
    {
        //do something if the key is found.
    }
    else
    {
        //do something else if the key isn't found in the dictionary.
    }
}
```

**To get this to work you would need to create the dictionary as follows:**

```
var valueComboMapping = Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
```

Instead of:

```
var valueComboMapping = Dictionary<string, int[]>();
```

Comment: That's not my point. I want to call these three values by simply choosing one entry. But I don't know if it is even possible to refer 3 values to one Item, that's why I asked if there is an easier way to save these 3 values somewhere, and calling them by pressing a button or something.

Comment: So you want only 1 entry in the comboBox that it made up of the 3 values?

Comment: is it possible to save the values under one comboboxitem, but don't concatenate them? I mean like: save them under the name (example: Entry 1), and when you choose entry one and press another button, these values saved under the name entry one will be used to calculate something with.

Comment: @SebDammer - so you don't actually want to display these 3 values in the comboBox? You just want an entry in the comboBox that refers to the 3 values?

Comment: I don't really get how the dictionary works. How do I make use of it? I mean, it works in that case that I can make entries which are shown under a name in the ComboBox. But how do I call these entries? I want that the saved entries (Example Entry1) can be taken and defined as new integers.

Somehow like:
                if (comboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    int betrag = [Somehow to take a value out of the dictionary....] }

Comment: @SebDammer - the Dictionary works on the basis that each 'Key' is a unique value, and against that you store what ever values you want. You then get these values out of the dictionary based on the key. So if you initially store '1', '2' and '3' as the values against "Entry 1", you can then get the values out of the Dictionary by using the key of "Entry 1".

Comment: @SebDammer -  in your case it looks like you want to get the values out of the dictionary when the SelectedIndexChanged event is fired. If so you get the value of the SelectedIndex and use that as the value for the key to retrieve the values.

Comment: @SebDammer - example added for retrieving values.

Comment: did everything you said, and I got the point. But it still shows 2 (for me) unknown errors: CS0029 Cannot implicity convert type 'system[..]List<int>' to 'System.Windows.Documents.List' and CS0103 name 'valueComboMapping' does not exist in the current context. Do you got any idea why it doesnt work?

Comment: @SebDammer - you will need to make sure that the dictionary valueComboMapping is instantiated as a global variable. As for the list error, make sure you have a using statement for System.Collections.Generic.

Answer (score 0):

> You can add directly to combobox,no need to add to list.You are using int.Parse, it will generate Format exception.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     comboBox1.Items.Add(betrag1.Text);
     comboBox1.Items.Add(monate1.Text);
     comboBox1.Items.Add(zins1.Text);                    
 }
```